# Is it possible to use custom DH parameters for IKEv1 / IKEv2 /IPSEC?

Tags: diffie-hellman, ipsec, ike

While researching how to deploy TLS for web servers most securely, I have learned that using custom DH parameters is one of the key aspects.

Now I am in the process of deploying IKE / IPSEC. As far as I have understood, IKEv1 as well as IKEv2 only support standard DH parameters which are denoted by standardized group names.

Does that mean that I cannot use my own custom DH parameters for IKEv1/2 (as generated by `openssl dhparam`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that I cannot use my own custom DH parameters for IKEv1/2 (as generated by openssl dhparam)?

Yes, only predefined MODP and ECP DH groups may be used with IKE, the lists for [IKEv2](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ikev2-parameters/ikev2-parameters.xhtml#ikev2-parameters-8) and [IKEv1](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipsec-registry/ipsec-registry.xhtml#ipsec-registry-10) can be found at IANA.

If you don't care for interoperability you could, of course, define your own group and use an identifier from the *private use* range.